# Bevel object: disproportionate

Tags: bevel

I use a bevel object to contour the shape of a bezier curve - why
is the bevel object disproportionate compared to the final shape?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When scaling your bezier curve, you wont affect the bevel object. If you want to control the shape of your curve geometry you can scale the bevel object.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easier way to place the bevel object on the curve to match the shape (which I find intuitive)? I rotated it in object mode (x=90°, z=-45°) and placed it on the first control point.

Comment: I can't see what you want to achieve. Do you want the bevel object to be where the bezier curve begins?